# Button.when_activated event is not firing even though Button.is_active is setting correctly

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, gpiozero

Thanks in advance!

I am using a Pi 3B to detect activation of a sensor on my model railroad layout. The sensor by default only offers a rising edge detection scenario. I decided to go with gpiozero library to setup a `gpiozero.Button` on GPIO 17, with `pull_up=False`.

[image]

I am facing this strange situation where the `button.is_active` is correctly set when the sensor is active, but the `button.when_activated` event is not firing on the rising edge. When the sensor deactivates, both the `when_activated` and `when_deactivated` events are fired.

I wrote a test script which sets up the event handlers, and also sets up a while loop to monitor the button.is_active property.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from gpiozero import InputDevice
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import DigitalInputDevice
from signal import pause
from datetime import datetime

# event handlers
def activated(self):
    print(f"{datetime.now()}: Activated {str(self.pin.number)}")

def deactivated(self):
    print(f"{datetime.now()}: Deactivated {str(self.pin.number)}")

# Set GPIO 17 with pull down resistor
button = Button(17, pull_up=False,  bounce_time=0.2)

# Set up handlers
button.when_activated = activated
button.when_deactivated = deactivated

# Loop to monitor button active state
state = button.is_active
while (True):

    # Create a debounce
    condition1 = button.is_active != state
    if condition1:
        sleep(0.4)
        new_state = button.is_active
        condition2 = new_state != state
        if condition2:

            # Print states and set the stored state to new state 
            print(f"{datetime.now()}: Stored state value is {state} and Button is {new_state}")
            state = new_state
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
2022-03-12 07:52:11.679051: Stored state value is False and Button is True
2022-03-12 07:52:20.950999: Activated 17
2022-03-12 07:52:21.146104: Deactivated 17
2022-03-12 07:52:21.351971: Stored state value is True and Button is False
```

The `button.is_active` was detected in the while loop at 7:52:11, but the `when_activated` event fired only when the sensor deactivated and the two events (`when_activated`, `when_deactivated`) are packed along with the `button.is_active` detection on the falling edge.

Any thoughts what might be going on? Any help is much appreciated. This situation is driving me bonkers.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Bullseye OS. The gpiozero library is 1.6.1

---

Comment: Thanks CoderMike. But, "self" is just a convention in Python. Its not a reserved word, like "this" in Java/C#. http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html. I will try to see if there is some issue going on with the GPIOThreadQueue. I am going through the gpiozero code base. There is a lot going on with GPIOThread and Thread queues. But, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT import classes you don't need `from gpiozero import InputDevice` - this may not hurt but wastes memory and makes the code harder to follow.

If you are using callbacks DO NOT attempt to test the state.
`Button` DOES NOT have a member `is_active` (although the base class may have you SHOULD NOT use it).

Get rid of everything after `# Loop to monitor button active state` and it should work.
You will need `pause()` or similar.
See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/faq.html?highlight=pause()#how-do-i-keep-my-script-running

Your Question lacks detail about what is connected.

---

You said "The sensor by default only offers a rising edge detection scenario" but is an opto-isolator, which imposes no such condition.

Your circuit has a number of limitations.

1. A bare 3.3V connection is a potential hazard, usually avoided by engineers.
2. The internal pullup/pulldown are weak ~50kΩ and subject to interference/noise - which is to be expected where motors are involved.

I would use a low impedance circuit with an external low resistance pullup (~1kΩ).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcq6Dy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This should satisfy the electrical requirements, although depending on the nature of the unspecified sensor and expected function may need additional conditioning (hardware and/or software).

As no Button is in use DO NOT use the Button class use `DigitalInputDevice`.

Comment: Thanks Milliways for the quick response. Please see a picture of the setup I have on my model railroad. Its a current detector which has a Opto-isolator output. There is no way to make the output work other than as an active-high system. I tried with the DigitalInputDeivce and faced the same challenge of the two events firing at the deactivation of the sensor. I added the while loop only to test the system, otherwise  the whole code runs as part of a TCP server on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Sorry Milliways, I should have added that final detail on why I said its rising-edge only. The device i use is a Quad Current Detector with Common positive for all the four opto-isolators. The collectors of all the four opto-detectors are tied together and I dont have a way to access them individually. I get access to the four emitters only. I will try to run it as a DigitalInputDevice only and see if it will help.

Comment: @SreekarKrishna It should make no difference which way it is wired, BUT running bare 3.3V wiring has the possibility of shorting the 3.3V rail - which will most likely destroy the Pi. But use sensible pulldown otherwise you are just connecting an antenna to your GPIO. You could use a small (10Ω) resistor in the 3.3V line near the Pi for protection and should not affect operation.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks for that suggestion. I will include a small resistor for protection purposes.